# How to get user from Request in nest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I can't get user from request in decorator nest, pleas help me.
Middleware good working it find user by token and save user in request
my middleware:

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpException } from '@nestjs/common/exceptions/http.exception';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../modules/authentication-v1/authentication.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
    constructor(
        private readonly authenticationService : AuthenticationService
    ) {
    }
    async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
        let token = req.headers;

        if(!token) {
            throw new HttpException('token is required', 401);
        }

        if (!token.match(/Bearer\s(\S+)/)) {
            throw new HttpException('Unsupported token', 401);
        }
        const [ tokenType, tokenValue ] = token.split(' ');
        try {
            const result = await this.authenticationService.getAccessToken(tokenValue);
            req.user = result;
            next();
        } catch (e) {
            throw new HttpException(e.message, 401);
        }
    }
}
```

but here request don't have property user and i don't know why
user decorator:

```
export const User = createParamDecorator((data: any, req) => {
    return req.user; // but here user undefined
});
```

app module:

```
export class AppModule {
    configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
        consumer
            .apply(AuthenticationMiddleware)
            .forRoutes({ path: 'auto-reports-v1', method: RequestMethod.GET });
    }
}
```

route method:

```
@UseInterceptors(LoggingInterceptor)
@Controller('auto-reports-v1')
@ApiTags('auto-reports-v1')
export class AutoReportsController {
    constructor(private readonly autoReportsService: AutoReportsService) {}

    @Get()
    async findAll(
        @Query() filter: any,
        @User() user: any): Promise<Paginated> {
        return this.autoReportsService.findPaginatedByFilter(filter, user);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your version of Nest common and core?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel 6.11.11

Comment: Hmm, that's the right version for that factory. Have you checked what your `req` is in the decorator? I can't see anything immediately wrong.

Comment: yes, in user decorator i have another request but i don't why

Comment: i found, user was set in req.raw.user

Comment: Are you using Fastify?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel yes, its a problem?

Comment: Not a problem, just explains what was happening. The middleware runs before the request gets wrapped by the FastifyRequest object, hence why it is on `req.raw` instead of `req`. Definitely good information to add in the future

Comment: can i change it?

Comment: Change what? I'm not sure what "it" refers to here

Comment: start middleware after was started FastifyRequest

Comment: Nope. [Middleware is the first thing to run](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/request-lifecycle). You could handle it later in a [guard](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards) though, and that will bind to the fastify request not the incoming request, meaning `req.user` not `req.raw.user`. For any more questions you may have, and further discussion, I suggest you visit the [Discord](https://discord.gg/nestjs)

Comment: thank you, for help)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In NestJS with Fastify, middleware attaches values to `req.raw`. This is because middleware runs before the request gets wrapped by the `FastifyRequest` object, so all value attachments are made to the `IncomingRequest` object (same as Express Request object). Fastify will then wrap the `IncomingRequest` in its own `FastifyRequest` object and expose the `IncomingRequest` through `req.raw` meaning the user you are looking for is at `req.raw.user` not `req.user`. If you want to have the same functionality across Express and Fastify, I'd suggest using a Guard instead.

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer didn't help me, but the ["custom decorators" from nest js documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators)  uses createParamDecorator with ExecutionContext as second parameter, and this worked for me:

```html
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';

export const User = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return request.user;
  },
);
```

Comment: Actually, on fastify, `getRequest` returns the wrapped `FastifyRequest`, so the code you want to use is :
```ts
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';

export const User = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return request.raw.user;
  },
);
```